# How do I use AnkoComponent inside FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebaseui, anko

I have this FirebaseRecyclerAdapter:

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatHolder>(
Chat.class, 
// Below layout is where I want the AnkoComponent
android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, 
ChatHolder.class, 
mRef) {
    @Override
    public void populateViewHolder(ChatHolder chatMessageViewHolder, Chat chatMessage, int position) {
        chatMessageViewHolder.setName(chatMessage.getName());
        chatMessageViewHolder.setText(chatMessage.getText());
    }
};
recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I want to use an AnkoComponent that is in a different file than the adapter. If anybody could help me with this I would be so grateful.

Just in case it helps, below is the AnkoComponent that I want to use as my list item in the viewHolder.

```
class PriorityUI : AnkoComponent<Priority> {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<Priority>) = with(ui) {

        relativeLayout {
            id = R.id.priority_item_layout
            linearLayout {
                orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL

                textView {
                    id = R.id.textView_priority
                    textAlignment = Gravity.CENTER
                }.lparams {
                    width = matchParent
                }

            }.lparams {
                width = matchParent
            }
        }
    }
}
```